# Rails association filter showing IDs instead of names

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am using ReportsKit gem to create charts in my Rails 5 application. I have two models, `Author` and `Post`, where an author `has_many` posts. I have successfully created a chart, with a Multi-Autocomplete filter. The filter is supposed to list the names of the Authors, but instead it lists model IDs in the format `#<Author:0X0007f2c85fc83f8>`.

Here is my yml:

```
measure: post
filters:
- author
dimensions:
- created_at
- author
chart:
  options:
    scales:
      xAxes:
      - stacked: true
      yAxes:
      - stacked: true
```

Here is the view:

```
= render_report 'interaction_filter_multi_autocomplete' do |report|
  = report.form do |f|
    = f.multi_autocomplete :author, placeholder: 'Author...'
```

How can I have authors being instead instead of the strange codes?

Comment: You need to pass an array of author names (String) instead of models (ActiveRecord) to the helper, maybe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to override the to_s method in the model to this:

```
def to_s
  name
end
```

Thanks to the good folks at the reports_kit github pages!